# Angular Dropdown slice: 0:50 not shown selected value after slice

Tags: html, angular

Sample html code

```
<nx-dropdown-item
    *ngFor="let profession of occupationProfessionChanges$ | async | slice: 0:50"
    [nxValue]="profession?.code"
    attr.data-id="{{ 'occupationProfession-' + profession.code }}"
    >
    {{ profession?.name }}
</nx-dropdown-item>
```

- The list has 200 options, the dropdown shows first 50 options .
- Now if i select 70th option, the value successfully passing to backend.
- When i visit back the page the selected 70th option was not shown on UI, it
  has been selected and hidden.

Please suggest any solution for this case.

Comment: I suggest use a typeahead, (personal opinion:use a dropdown with more that 20 elements looks like me a crazy idea)

Comment: you can use https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/data-sources, for the dropdown list in angular.

visit the library page https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select

Answer (score 0):

I have created one demo in the https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-ohzqzo, as your concern is about the performance.

I really suggest you to use **ng-select**, as it has wide range of features that your can leverage.